I get Error while run the url for IP Webcam
WARNING ⚠️ Unable to automatically guess model task, assuming 'task=detect'. Explicitly define task for your model, i.e. 'task=detectt', 'segment', 'classify','pose' or 'obb'.
[http @ 00000265b0ce1a80] Stream ends prematurely at 40818, should be 18446744073709551615
[http @ 00000265b0ce1a80] Stream ends prematurely at 40818, should be 18446744073709551615

Code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO
from sort.sort import Sort
from util import read_license_plate
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import io


class LicensePlateDetector:
    def __init__(self, model_path):
        self.model = YOLO(model_path)

    def detect(self, frame):
        return self.model(frame)[0]


class LicensePlateProcessor:
    @staticmethod
    def process(license_plate_crop):
        if license_plate_crop.size == 0:
            return None
        license_plate_crop_gray = cv2.cvtColor(license_plate_crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, license_plate_crop_thresh = cv2.threshold(
            license_plate_crop_gray, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV
        )
        return license_plate_crop_thresh

    @staticmethod
    def read(license_plate_crop_thresh):
        if license_plate_crop_thresh is None or license_plate_crop_thresh.size == 0:
            return None, 0
        return read_license_plate(license_plate_crop_thresh)


def main():
    st.title("Live Stream License Plate Detection")

    video_url = st.text_input("Enter video stream URL (http/rtsp):")

    if video_url:
        license_plate_detector = LicensePlateDetector(
            ""
        )
        license_plate_processor = LicensePlateProcessor()

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_url)

        if not cap.isOpened():
            st.error("Error opening video stream.")
            return

        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if not ret:
                st.error("Error reading frame.")
                break

            # Process frame
            license_plates = license_plate_detector.detect(frame)

            for license_plate in license_plates.boxes.data.tolist():
                x1, y1, x2, y2, score, class_id = license_plate

                license_plate_crop = frame[int(y1) : int(y2), int(x1) : int(x2), :]
                license_plate_crop_thresh = license_plate_processor.process(
                    license_plate_crop
                )
                license_plate_text, license_plate_text_score = (
                    license_plate_processor.read(license_plate_crop_thresh)
                )

                if license_plate_text is not None:
                    # Draw bounding box on frame
                    cv2.rectangle(
                        frame, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (0, 255, 0), 2
                    )
                    cv2.putText(
                        frame,
                        license_plate_text,
                        (int(x1), int(y1) - 10),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.9,
                        (36, 255, 12),
                        2,
                    )

                    # Display result
                    st.image(frame, channels="BGR", use_column_width=True)

        cap.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


First format your question
